# Laravel Vue js spa application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server, vue-router

### 1).

i want to know why people use two servers to make a vuejs SPA with laravel.
 I think we can use the other way. Make a Route like this

```
 Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any' , ".*");
```

and let vue handle the page url..
why people are using 2 servers and then using laravel passport to authenticate when we dont need to do all this to make spa..

### 2).

Okay now suppose we have our spa readdy using 2 separate servers one for `vue` and one for `laravel`.

Now i don't know how to set **two servers** on a single remove server.?
how should i upload both vue and laravel applications on a single server on internet and make them work together.

Comment: Where are you seeing examples of two servers? Are you referring to the web server and webpack dev server?

Comment: yes one is webpack server and one is laravel server .. but that is the second point. i have to make a spa and firstly i got to know why people are using these 2 servers instead of just using the other way i discribed above. and if they are using it how are  they gonna combine them.

Comment: 1. you can do it like this, yes. 2. it can also make sense to separate API server and application (vue). For example, if API is hosted on whole other doman, so they can be deployed independently. If it's the same machine it makes sense to use single server like in 1.

Comment: It's important to first understand what the webpack dev server actually is and what it's doing. It is not a production tool. It's there for development purposes so you can utilize things like `watch` and `hot reloading`. It does not supplant or compliment the web server outside of a development environment. And as to your question about the catch all route, you'll need that regardless as it allows direct browser navigation within the SPA.

Comment: okay @dfsq i got you. thank you for this. but i wan't to know one more thing.. there isn't any sense or there is no way that we can upload an application which is made by using two servers and upload the application on one server ..? i just want to know can we or we cant .?

Comment: I know that webpack dev server is just a development tool. the thing that is making me confuse is. though it is a development server but by using it now our vue application is using api service to do everything from another server .. everything is now setup for two servers .. so now if someone want to upload this project to a single server on internet . is it possible ..? @btl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bit of religion of some sort, but there is no right or wrong answer. Both have benefits and disadvantages.

A few of the benefits I can think of on top of my head is:

Reusability. You've made an API now everyone and everything can use this API, wanna make an IOS app to your web application as well? Well, go right on you have a 100% functional and tested API already.

Expertise: It's easy for your team to split up and work on what they know.

Deployment: Frontend and backend can be deployed, and tested, separately which can give you a big amount of freedom.

So basically how you could set this up very fast. is install a laravel/lumen application where you have the API serve with your preferred choice homestead, nginx, artisan serve etc.

then take a new vuejs/ReactJS etc. server and set it up. then all your API calls referer to the localhost your Laravel application is running on.

Comment: thank you this is answer of my first point. totally get it. i just want to know 1 more thing. if someone has an application which is made using a vue dev server and a laravel server.. can we upload both the applications on a single server online .??

Comment: Well yes you can, i don't see the reason to do this, except it might save you 5$ (on a low server) a month :) But it's indeed possible

Comment: You are the best @casper