# work with laravel as backend and angular as frontend

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-5

i am starting a project i want know that what is the best and most accepted way of using angular as front end and laravel as back end

can i do like in view folder of laravel i will install angular is it ok??

i tried to create api for that and in angluar i will call that api.

what is the most used way for doing this i have seen tutorials over this but most of the tuts are for angular version 2 and its outdated

so can you please tell me any way to work laravel 5.6 and angular 5 or 4 together

please give me your suggestion and thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basiclly there are two ways you can do this.

One keep everything in one app, and do as you suggested and put in /view. Laravel has a `php artisan preset react` which sets the application up for React, but as far as i know there is not one for angular but sure you can find a tutorial on how to include Angular in your Laravel project.

The second way is keeping them seperated having a Laravel/Lumen app that provides there API, and a another project that has the Angular project running, than your Angular project will be calling the Laravel's api through two seperate servers running on Localhost example. I just answered another simillar questions of the benefits of doing it like this.

Read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181795/2783379

Answer (score 2):

You can view the documenation page of angular and laravel.

I think, this is the best way and it can help you to achieve your project using the two technology.

https://laravel-angular.io/

Installation:

```
composer require jadjoubran/laravel-angular
```

If you're using Laravel 5.5 or newer, you can skip this step.
Inside your config/app.php, add the Service Provider:

```
Jadjoubran\LaravelAngular\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class
```

Then run the installation command:

```
php artisan laravelangular:install
```

Source: https://laravel-angular.io/docs/1/

Comment: I do not believe this is an `official` But yes this is a method :)!

Comment: Update answer! :p :p

Answer (score 1):

I should stick with making an Laravel API and let your Angular app make calls to that API. This is the most common approach these days.

Comment: yes whatever i have searched for this api is one of the best option