# How can I implement Laravel 5.5 and Angular 4 project intogether?

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5.5

If I want to implement Angularjs 4 or 2 with Laravel 5.5 (angular will consume the API from laravel), what should be the best method? 1) Should I create two folders in xampp/htdocs like c:/xampp/htdocs/test-laravel55 and c:/xampp/htdocs/test-angular4 OR 2) Should I create a project of laravel 5.5 like c:/xampp/htdocs/test-laravel55 and put the angularjs4 (e2e, node_modules, src) files & folders into test-laravel55?

If method 1 is better, can you kindly recommend me some links/ videos to understand how will be the process like CRUD operations, Auth login, etc. Also, if method 2 is better, can you suggest me some links/ videos about the procedure / tutorials, CRUD operations, Auth login etc?

My main moto is "admin user" can login to the admin panel and create some CRUD operations like category creation, product creation etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [work with laravel as backend and angular as frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405501/work-with-laravel-as-backend-and-angular-as-frontend)

Comment: Have not find my solutions from this link, yet

Comment: Since they are different projects, and Angular doesn't benefit from being located in backend directory, it makes sense to put them in different folders. It doesn't really belong to xampp/htdocs because Angular alone isn't served with Apache.

Comment: Thanks! @estus . Can you please suggest me a demo application or demo CRUD tutorials in Laravel5.5 with Angularjs 2 / 4?

Comment: I can't, but there's a plenty of them on github with relevant keywords https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=angular+laravel+demo&ref=opensearch&s=updated&type=Repositories

Comment: I'm taking - shakyl333/Laravel-5.5-Angular-4-demo as first tutorial.

Comment: Should be separate repo for both angular and laravel. it is a best practice.   even after you want to have both in single repo.  You can install angular at `public/js` of laravel project

Comment: for login you can use `jwt-token` something like that. This may helps you  http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

my approach is to make 2 completely separate projects one for Laravel and you should put it in your localhost root
and the other is for Angular and you can put it anywhere

**Laravel Project**

you will work only with routes and controllers no views required and for sure connecting to database, you can use Postman to test your REST APIs and functionality.

**Angular Project**

you will handle all front-end routes and views here you just call your back-end APIs (laravel project) to get and set data.

when you build the Angular project via `ng build` it will create a folder called `dist` this folder is the client side for your project you should point to it with you domain name once you deploy your project on any hosting service provider and for the Laravel project you may point to it with a subdomain

***Example***

you created a laravel project and hosted it at *app.yourwebsite.com*
you created an Angular project and build it then uploaded the dist folder to *yourwebsite.com*

now when a user hits *yourwebsite.com*
he will see the front-end of your angular app then in behind it calls *app.yourwebsite.com* via HTTP requests to get/set data

you can find more useful info and examples here https://laravel-angular.io/

**Answering your questions**

1- dist folder is created via `ng build`
2- you will upload the dist folder only as it contain all compiled angular app
3- any hosting server will be accepted because you will host JS/HTML files only so you don't need any compilers or nodejs/npm environment

Comment: Thanks! Now, I understood the flow entirely. I find a demo project from https://github.com/shakyl333/Laravel-5.5-Angular-4-demo. I did not see any dist folder under https://github.com/shakyl333/Laravel-5.5-Angular-4-demo/tree/master/ngAngular. Can you please tell me how to create a dist folder there? Should I upload the dist folder ONLY to the yourwebsite.com? Which kind of hosting server should I hire to run angularjs as I know Apache will not help to run angular. Kindly answers the questions.

Comment: I have created the dist folder by putting the command ng build. Can you please answer my rest questions as above?

Comment: Another question - If I upload the dist folder in to the server, will it run automatically like http://www.myservername.com OR, should I configure something additional within the server?

Comment: Yes, it should run automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

what if you want to:
have laravel website at: http://site.localhost
and have an Angular admin inside that, at: http://site.localhost/admin

I tried to put resources at root of laravel public (assets & js), make my view in resources/views/admin with:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    View::addExtension('html', 'php');
    return View::make('admin.index');
} )->name('admin');
```

and build with `ng build --prod --aot --base-href /admin`

the problem is now that the base href also applies to CSS, so loading fontawesome looks for: http://site.localhost/admin/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0

but my assets are on root of public not inside "admin", and if I add an "admin" folder inside public, I get a 'Forbidden' page on site.localhost/admin...