# How to deploy angular 5 project in Laravel?

Tags: php, angular, laravel, angular5

How to deploy the build of the angular 5 project in Laravel? I am deploying the build files of angular in Laravel, it is working everything fine but when I refresh after routing to any page is showing 404. The reason is it will check the controller in the backend with that URL. I tried to avoid this problem by using hash strategy but I am thinking it is not a good idea. So please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement Laravel 5.5 and Angular 4 project intogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422271/how-can-i-implement-laravel-5-5-and-angular-4-project-intogether)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97BggEw0dJI have a look

Comment: For that you have apply URL re-write rules by just adding `.htaccess` in root directory refer this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19009, or If you don't want to add `.htaccess` file then you have to enable your router to the HashLocationStrategy like this `RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: true })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in `Angular` [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19009) use following `.htaccess` file to load the same page of angular on refresh.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

If your index.html file is not in your root folder then you have to change the path of `index.html` as where your `index.html` exist,

like my `index.html` is in `resources/views/` then i will write the rule in `.htaccess` as :

```
RewriteRule ^ resources/views/index.html [L]
```